# Highlighting and keyboard-quit

Tags: mark

Why does `(keyboard-quit)` (bound to `C-g`) unmark the selected region? And is there a way to stop Emacs from doing so?

The sceneraio I have in mind is the following: suppose I select a region and begin a `C-c C-` command, but I change my mind and want to cancel. If I call `(keyboard-quit)`, I also lose the selection.

Comment: Clarify the use case/question. In what context do you need the region to not become inactive? Would re-activating it suffice? And so on.

Comment: Can `C-]` help?

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: It cancels `C-c C-c` and preserves the selection. Do a try.

Comment: @Name, in my mind, that is the correct answer, you should post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by abo-abo, the function `keyboard-quit` explicitly deactivates the mark.  While you could in principle edit this function, it is better to advise it so that it conditionally reactivates the mark if it was active before.  Since `keyboard-quit` may exit by signalling a condition, you must do that in an `unwind-protect` unwind handler:

```
(defun my-keyboard-quit-advice (fn &rest args)
  (let ((region-was-active (region-active-p)))
    (unwind-protect
         (apply fn args)
      (when region-was-active
        (activate-mark t)))))

(advice-add 'keyboard-quit :around #'my-keyboard-quit-advice)
```

Answer (score 4):

As you can see from the code, it's specifically designed to do that:

```
(defun keyboard-quit ()
  "Signal a `quit' condition.
During execution of Lisp code, this character causes a quit directly.
At top-level, as an editor command, this simply beeps."
  (interactive)
  ;; Avoid adding the region to the window selection.
  (setq saved-region-selection nil)
  (let (select-active-regions)
    (deactivate-mark)) ;;<------------- umark selected region
  (if (fboundp 'kmacro-keyboard-quit)
      (kmacro-keyboard-quit))
  (when completion-in-region-mode
    (completion-in-region-mode -1))
  ;; Force the next redisplay cycle to remove the "Def" indicator from
  ;; all the mode lines.
  (if defining-kbd-macro
      (force-mode-line-update t))
  (setq defining-kbd-macro nil)
  (let ((debug-on-quit nil))
    (signal 'quit nil)))
```

Comment: Nice to know this. So if I redefine this function and do not include that command, everything will work fine, right?

Comment: Yep, most likely. The important part is just `(signal 'quit nil)`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Even if I leave he whole function body empty, the undesired behavior occurs.